# How to initialize a `List<KeyValuePair<string, HashSet<string>>>` properly?

Tags: c#

I simply wish to add some elements in a `List<KeyValuePair<string, HashSet<string>>>` but when trying to do so the `value` in `KeyValuePair` gets changed automatically

Initialized a few containers as shown below

```
HashSet<string> txtFiles = new HashSet<string>();
List<KeyValuePair<string, HashSet<string>>> logTxtFilesList = new List<KeyValuePair<string, HashSet<string>>>();
```

Now this is how I'm adding elements

```
DirectoryInfo dirInfo = new DirectoryInfo(directoryPath);
recentFiles = dirInfo.EnumerateFiles()
string pattern = ^.*\|END_OF_PARAM\|([A-Za-z0-9_-]+\.txt)$

foreach (FileInfo file in recentFiles)
{
    txtFiles.Clear();

    using (FileStream fs = File.Open(file.FullName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite))
    using (BufferedStream bs = new BufferedStream(fs))
    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(bs))
    {
        string line;
        while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            Match match = Regex.Match(line, pattern);

            if (match.Success)
            {
                FileName = match.Groups[1].ToString();
                if (txtFiles.Add(FileName))
                {
                    // Some DB insertion
                }
            }
        }
        logTxtFilesList.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, HashSet<string>>(file.Name, txtFiles)); //After the first file is read completely lets say it has a new element (abc.txt as key and HashSet<string> as value with 500 elements)
    }
```

After second iteration is completed the second element is added in `logTxtFilesList` lets say (xyz.txt as key and HashSet as value with 300 elements **but the first element's value count which was 500 is now set to 300 and is replaced by the new HashSet** )
}

So basically after every iteration the previous value in `logTxtFilesList` is replaced with a new one. This is the problem.

Please let me know where am I going wrong
Let me know if any additional data is needed.
Thanks

Answer (score 4):

In every iteration of your loop, you're clearing the HashSet `txtFiles` and storing a reference to this in every `KeyValuePair`. So all `KeyValuePairs` point to the same HashSet.

If you replace

```
txtFiles.Clear();
```

with

```
var hashSet = new HashSet<string>();
```

that problem would be solved.

Comment: `var txtFiles` instead of `var hashSet` :)

Comment: Ohh, was not knowing that it is being passed by reference and not by value. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Like others pointed out, you are reusing an instance of `HashSet<string>` in `txtFiles`.
Objects are passed by reference, not value. That means when you execute

`logTxtFilesList.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, HashSet<string>>(file.Name, txtFiles));`

The value of `txtFiles` is not a list of txt files but a reference to a list of txt files which you continuosly mutate on each iteration, therefore at the end of the loop, all your entries in `logTxtFilesList` will contain exactly the same set of `txtFiles` as they refer to the same list.

All you need to do is remove the line

```
HashSet<string> txtFiles = new HashSet<string>();
```

and place it instead of

```
txtFiles.Clear();
```